# AggregateException Not Thrown in Task.Run()

Tags: c#, aggregateexception

I am trying to catch an AggregateException from a Task.Run() operation which intentionally fails, however an AggregateException is not thrown. Why?

```
public void EnterWaitingRoom(string val)
{
    try
    {
      Task.Run(() => InvokeHubMethod("HubMethod", 
         new object[] { val }));
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        // This exception is not caught
        throw ex;
    }
}

private async Task<object> InvokeHubMethod(string method, object[] args)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => _hubProxy.Invoke<object>(method, 
        args).Result);
}
```

I expect the exception to be thrown but it is not.
I also tried adding .Wait and still don't get the exception.
The request is coming from a windows UI.
Any ideas.  Thanks.

Comment: You're not waiting on your task in `EnterWaitingRoom`, so the exception won't be thrown

Comment: And when you await the AggregateException will be unwrapped to the inner exception => no AggregateException

Comment: I tried Task.Run(()=>...).Wait() and still not exception thrown.

Comment: Of course, you wait for the task that will return a task

Comment: @SirRufo You are correct that the `Task.Run` calls are inappropriate and shouldn't be used, but incorrect to state that there's a `Task<Task>`.  It's inefficient, redundant, confusing, and wasteful, but it does return a `Task<object>`.

Comment: @Sir Rufo - The EnterWaitingRoom function is called from a button click.  It then calls an async method InvokeHubMethod.  As far as I know this should work.

Comment: @Servy gotcha ;o)

Comment: @Servy I've removed Task.Run() and am just calling the async fuction this way

  InvokeHubMethod("HubMethod",  new object[] { val }).ContinueWith(t=>
         {
             if (t.IsFaulted)
             {
                     // Catch error here
              }
         });
This seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you enter the `async/await` from an EventHandler

```
public async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args )
{
    object result = await EnterWaitingRoom( "whatever" );
}

private Task<object> EnterWaitingRoom(string val)
{
    return InvokeHubMethod(
        "HubMethod",
        new object[] { val } );
}

private Task<object> InvokeHubMethod(string method, object[] args)
{
    return _hubProxy.Invoke<object>(
        method, 
        args);
}
```